# Basic draggable with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I don't want draggable sortable elements or anything fancy, just a draggable element, like a normal jQuery div draggable object:

```
$("#draggable").draggable();
```

What is the proper way to do this through Angular? Do I still use jQueryUI, or is there anything in AngularUI I can use? I looked through both Angular libraries but didn't find anything specifically addressing draggable objects.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use a directive.

Example:

```
angular.module("myApp").directive('andyDraggable', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      var options = scope.$eval(attrs.andyDraggable); //allow options to be passed in
      elm.draggable(options);
    }
  };
});
```

HTML

```
<div andy-draggable>Drag me!</div>
<div andy-draggable="{key: value}">Drag me with options!</div>
```

Documentation on directives: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

You could also create data-binding for the element's current position during the drag, hook up events, etc.  But this is a really basic version.

Comment: No need to wrap `elm` in jQuery. It already *is* a jQuery object. Angular pre-wraps all elements in jQuery (if it's available. Otherwise it uses its own jqLite).

Comment: Tried it with no luck. No errors, but it's not making the element draggable. I double checked that jQueryUI was working by defining an id (temporarily) and adding draggable and that worked. Is there a particular order I have to add the jQuery libraries? They are defined at the end of my page currently. The angular ones are at the top (including the controller/directive).

Comment: You should include jQuery before angular... though that shouldn't mess up this in particular.  Are you sure the directive is being run?  Are you including the file the directive is defined in?

Comment: I tried jQuery before and after with no effect. I'm not actually sure the directive is being run at all since I threw an alert and console.log and nothing happened. I'm sure the file is being included though since I had a function that was doing some other things in it (after that part). I've since stripped it down, but still not getting anything. Could be missing a '}' or ';' somewhere I guess? Here's the snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/fwHcW/

Comment: Thanks! Based on that I figured out my problem was not translating the camel case to snake case letters for the directive in my HTML. That's technically two questions answered :)

Comment: +1 for a nice, simple, semantic example of how to use directives. 
You should edit your example to remove the jQuery wrapper from `elm` though, as @JosephSilber pointed out => `elm.draggable(options);`

Comment: Done, also added a prefix to the directive so people see camelCase to dash-case conversion.

Comment: I don't get it.  Nothing on [jsfiddle.net/QZ6kN/3](http://jsfiddle.net/QZ6kN/3) appears to drag.

Comment: I can't stop laughing @ `Drag me with options!` :D

Comment: can any one help,i am getting this error : elm.draggable is not a function