# Make ngDialog draggable AngularJs jQueryUI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui, draggable, ng-dialog

I am wanting to make ngDialog draggable, using jQueryUI, or just Angular (preferred).

Here is an example of the modal becoming draggable using jQueryUI:
[JSFiddle (Modal)](http://jsfiddle.net/qaoxfptL/1077/)

```
$(".modal").draggable({
    handle: ".modal-header"
});
```

I tried to replicate it with ngDialog, but was not able to do so.. [JSFiddle (ngDialog)](http://jsfiddle.net/swkg4rvn/)

```
$(".ngdialog ").draggable({
  handle: ".ngdialog-content"
});

// $(".ngdialog ").draggable();
```

Here is demo of a div being draggable using a directive: [JSFiddle (Directive)](http://jsfiddle.net/QZ6kN/3/), taken from this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589516/basic-draggable-with-angularjs).

```
app.directive('dragMe', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            elem.draggable();
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

put inside controller initialization:

```
$scope.$on('ngDialog.opened', function (e, $dialog) {
  $(".ngdialog").draggable({
    handle: ".ngdialog-content"
  });
});
```